# Clean way to set delegate on custom class through topviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, delegates

I've defined a class `NewViewController`, which shows a screen to add a new item in the app, which is wrapped in a `UINavigationController`. I want to set a `delegate` on this `UIViewController`, what I am currently doing in this way in the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
NewViewController *newViewController = (NewViewController *)navController.topViewController;
[newViewController setDelegate:self];
```

This works, but I have a feeling this is not elegant and not how I'm supposed to do this. What is the best approach to get this result?

Edit: The `delegate` in `NewViewController` is called when all the fields in the `NewViewController` are filled in and is submitted. For now that's the only thing that is `delegated` from `NewViewController`. The `UIViewController` that shows `NewViewController` modally is what is set as the `delegate` (thus self in this case).

Comment: maybe you can tell us a little bit more about the `delegates` and what you want to do with it inside the `NewViewController``

Comment: I updated the question with a bit more detail.

Comment: You can't set outlet connections between different viewcontrollers in storyboard, so this method seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this approach is fine, although you may want to do a little more error checking just in case. If this is a named segue, you can check `segue.identifier` to make sure this is the view controller you're expecting. I would also check the classes like so:

```
if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
{
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([navController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[NewViewController class]])
    {
        NewViewController *newViewController = (NewViewController *)navController.topViewController;
        [newViewController setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your doing is probably as clean as your going to get. Another method that would work but not as clean as what you have would be to use `NSNotificationCenter` to send an instance of `self` to `NewViewController`. I would stick with what you have.

Comment: To use it include `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver...]` inside the `UIViewController` you want to continue the process, and on the `UIButton` in the second `UIViewController` you add `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotifcationName...]`